# How to store "_ > _" in a val in Scala?

Tags: function, scala

In my case I wanted a flag to control which operator should be used by a function, I planned something like this:

```
val includeValue = *some value*

val include = _ => _
val exclude = _ > _

val operation = if (includeValue) include else exclude
```

Is this possible???

Comment: Doesn't it work? What's the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you can't store `_ > _` in a val, as is, with generics in any reasonable way.

`_ > _` represents a function that accepts two parameters. It calls the `>` method on the first parameter, and passes the second to it as an argument. We can't simply use wild-card types here, because not every type has a `>` method. Nor does it make sense to have a function from unknown to unknown like this.

We can try something simple, like making them `Int => Int`.

```
val includeValue = false
val include: (Int, Int) => Boolean = _ >= _
val exclude: (Int, Int) => Boolean = _ > _
val operation = if (includeValue) include else exclude

scala> operation(2, 2)
res72: Boolean = false

// with includeValue = true
scala> operation(2, 2)
res73: Boolean = true
```

But you're restricted to `Int` with this implementation. Maybe this is okay for you. If it's not, then you'll probably want to use the `Numeric` trait, but that will get rather messy using this notation.

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like this, if you want to define the operation for all types convertible to a `Comparable`:

```
def exclude[T <% Ordered[T]](a: T, b: T) = a > b
def include[T <% Ordered[T]](a: T, b: T) = a >= b
def operation[T <% Ordered[T]](a: T, b: T) = if (includeValue) include(a, b) else exclude(a, b)
```